# Аварийное отключение процессов на хостинге - Debian

Tags: сервер, debian, хостинг, vps

Добрый день.
На хостинге заказана услуга - VPS сервер и на нем развернут сайт. Параметры сервера:
Процессор   2000МГц
Память  1024МБ
OS  debian8-x86_64
дисковое пространство используется на 8%

Периодически приходят уведомления о том, что происходит аварийное отключение процессов на сервере, иногда это приводит к полной неработоспособности сайта.

Примеры уведомлений от сервера: 
Out of memory in UB 26507281: OOM killed process 264613 (/usr/share/webm) score 41 vm:109432kB, rss:43824kB, swap:0kB 
..... 
Out of memory in UB 26507281: OOM killed process 386173 (apache2) score 0 vm:294372kB, rss:36356kB, swap:0kB 
.....

Наибольшее количество запросов к сайту 41288 было зафиксировано с Ip-адреса - 66.249.64.219 (Googlebot)

Также пришел ответ от хостинга: 
Проблема с не корректной работой вашего сайта вероятно связана с некорректным завершением работы сервера баз данных:

170514  8:31:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170514  8:31:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170514  8:31:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda. 
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles! 
170514  8:31:54 InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally! 
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
 InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd    files... 
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the    doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...

На данный момент на сервере, если зайти на него через sftp не запускается ни одна команда, например, не работают команды:  apt-get, sudo, gedit, dpkg и т.д. Заходим на сервер под root. 
Как сделать, чтобы все команды заработали, как восстановить все сервисы на сервере?

И что делать с аварийно завершающимися процессами на сервере? 
Почему googlebot делает столько обращений к сайту - более 41 тыс? Это нормально?
Как настроить стабильную работу сервера?

Спасибо, за помощь.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: По сообщениям видно, что падает mysql - не хватает памяти. Работать без swap на 1ГБ памяти рискованно. Нужен swap на 1ГБ минимум. Пусть лучше подтормаживает, чем падает. В любом случае надо видеть настройки my.cnf, иметь сведения о веб-сервере, о сайте в общих чертах.